# did Google's Backup&Sync migrate my drive D?

Tags: online-backup

Suddenly I am getting messages 'Drive D low on free storage. I check:

- LocalDisk D: 504 MB
- Storage usage: 471 MB used, 32.9 MB free
- Other: 454 MB
- System&reserved: 16.1 MB
- Documents:…

What is this 'other' storage?

```
LocalDisk D: properties
> Events
    2018-04-11 21:23:48 Device migrated Device SCSI...was migrated
    2018-04-11 21:23:48     Device configured (disk inf)
    2018-04-11 21:23:49     Device started
```

2018-04-11 is the date I started Google's Backup&Sync.
Did Google 'migrate' my disk, and filled it with junk?

Comment: You tell us what is using your disk space, information to identify that ourselves, hasn’t been provided

Answer (score 0):

If you had data on Google Drive, prior to installing Backup and Sync, Google Drive might transfer the data from the cloud on to your drive.

If you want to keep the data that was in the Google Drive (cloud) separate from the Folder (on your computer) that you want to sync to Google Drive using Backup and Sync, you can just use different names for 2 folders.

If the folder existing in Google Drive Cloud is FolderA, then just use FolderB as the name of the folder on your computer.